# can't compile OpenCV 2.2 applications in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, opencv

I have opencv installed on a win7 64 bit machine. I can't get eclipse to link to the appropriate libraries / includes in the project.  All the documentation I can find is based on 2.1 or earlier and after 2.2 a lot of the structure was reorganized. I keep getting an error saying

> "C:\OpenCV2.2\include\opencv/highgui.h:47:39: fatal error:
>   opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 2):

Change `cv220`, ... to name of libraries in your lib folder. For example, if you have `libopencv_calib3d220.dll.a` in your lib folder, then in Eclipse link to this lib with name `libopencv_calib3d220` (without the `.dll.a`). It works!

Answer (score 0):

There is some 2.2 specific documentation [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/MinGW), building on VS2010 I did have to be careful to define all the include paths exactly as described.  And a lot of the examples aren't converted to 2.2 properly